# Hourglass cursor in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mouse-cursor, hourglass

Im currently making windows forms program (application),
and when the user logs into it, he must wait a few seconds before entering it.

My question is: **How to get the hourglass cursor, so the user will be informed that the program (app) is busy performing an operation?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use either

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.AppStarting
```

or

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
```

---

To set it back to the normal cursor:

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```